# Map dynamic field names while deserializing a JSON to a Java object

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I have an interesting problem that I want to solve. This is while I am parsing a response from one of the platforms that we interact with. The response changes based on the User.

Say for User A, I have the following JSON :

```
{
 "userId": "AA001",
 "AA001_Name": "Username",
 "AA001_Email": "user@gmail.com",
 "AA001_Phone": "000-000-0000"
}
```

For User B, I have :

```
{ 
  "userId" : "AA002",
  "AA002_Name" : "Username",
  "AA002_Email" : "user@gmail.com",
  "AA002_Phone" : "000-000-0000"
}
```

Now, while deserializing, I want to map both of them to the following object, ignoring the field name the json came with :

```
class User {
  private String userId,
  private String name,
  private String email,
  private String phone
}
```

It is easy to map the userId, as that's the field in the JSON as well, but what about the custom fields?

Now, I can't use the @JsonProperty as the name of the field is dynamically changing based on the user.

Is there any way this could be accomplished?
Please note that I might have several such custom objects like Department, Organization etc, and the platform returns the data in such a manner, meaning the keys have the user-specific information appended.

Any help is appreciated. I am badly stuck at this.

Comment: Probably you may check the JsonParser to parse the response to a JsonObject and then manually parse using a set of keys that you maintain. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do any better than using [`@JsonCreator`](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html):

```
class User {

    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    @JsonCreator
    public User(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.userId = (String) map.get("userId");
        map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().endsWith("_Name"))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(e -> this.name = (String) e.getValue());
        // repeat for other fields
    }

    // getters & setters (if needed)
}
```

You can change the stream by a traditional for each on the map's entry set to optimize performance-wise.

Comment: Alternative could use `@JsonAnySetter` for method that takes two arguments (key name, value), similar idea. The main benefit being that this would only be called if there is no fixed property to bind to, so you can combine properties with static name and "dynamic" properties.

Comment: @StaxMan `@JsonAnySetter` can receive a map as well, correct?

Comment: Thanks @Federico, this solution is a good start. My only other concern is if my custom object "User" has another custom object like "Address" in it or say a List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers, and each of those custom objects has field names different from the one that came from the platform, how do you think we should handle this?

Comment: @Partha I would need to test that, because I don't remember now. I'll do it in the weekend and will let you know.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes, but only as a value for a single unmapped property. Not as source for all unknown.

Comment: @StaxMan , Its a good suggestion for mix of dynamic and static properties, I have a use case for that and I am going to use it. Thanks.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner - I figured out about how to handle the custom objects and list of custom objects since we are customizing, we have to customize it all through. Thanks for your inputs, I followed your approach.

Comment: @Partha You're welcome! Do you mean that you cannot have `@JsonCreator` annotations in different constructors and let Jackson do all the work? You need to do all the mapping by yourself?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am seeing. If I leave out Custom mapping, jackson is ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use @JSONProperty as is, but what if you reformatted the keys before deserializing the JSON? I.E

```
  String key = "AA001_Name"
  String[] key = key.split("_") 
  key[0] = "AA001"
  key[1] = "Name"
  //Use key[1] as the new field name
```

Do this for each key, create a new JSON Object with the correct field names, then deserialize it.

Comment: This strategy won't work when I have say the following scenario, the platform response has "AA001_complete_name_with_spaces_and_salutation" and I want to plain map it to "fullName" in my Java object.

Comment: Hmm. Will the keys of your JSON object always be in the same order when you receive them? Will the keys always contain some part of the goal mapping? Is there any consistency to the JSON you receive?

Comment: That's a good point. There is no guarantee about the order of keys, its retrieved from a Map, and I am pretty sure they don't implement TreeMap, but maybe a vanilla HashMap implementation.